# Regex - match 'a' and 10 characters following php

Tags: php, regex

I'm looking for a regex to match a character 'a' and also the ten characters after it, no matter what they are.  So if I have a string `hello world a is a very nice letter`, it would match `a is a very`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to match that you can use this regex:

```
a.{10}
```

**[Working Demo](http://regex101.com/r/oL9gN5/1)**

By the way, if you want to get the content of the 10 characters, you can use the capturing groups:

```
a(.{10})
```

**[Working Demo](http://regex101.com/r/oL9gN5/1)**

[image]

Answer (score 4):

No need for a regex, just find the occurence of the X, and take 10 chars from there:

```
echo substr($string, strpos($string,'x'), 10);
```

String functions are extremely fast, compared to regexes. In case of simple string manipulation you should always go for the simple stringfunctions

Comment: It's not always true if your string contains multibyte characters. In this case you need to use `mb_substr` (and to ensure that mb is set to uft8). `substr` give you only the 10 first bytes but not the 10 first characters.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this regex:

```
x.{0,10}
```

#### [RegEx Demo](http://regex101.com/r/iE3vM0/1)

- `x` - matched literal `x`
- `.{0,10}` matches 0 to 10 characters after `x`

However for simple task like this it is better to use string functions and avoid regex.